# Getting 'role ___ does not exist' when running Django makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am attempting to connect a Django app to a local database, per the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes).

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'service': 'my_service',
            'passfile': '.my_pgpass',
        },
    }
}
```

My .pg_service.conf:

```
[my_service]
host=localhost
user=firstlast
dbname=my_db
port=5432
```

My .my_pgpass:

```
localhost:5432:my_db:firstlast:password
```

I've defined a new Model, and when I run `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` I get the following error:

```
/path/to/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:143:
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history 
performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at 
"localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "first" 
does not exist

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected in app 'myapp'
```

Note that the role in the error is different than the user defined in .pg_service.conf and .my_pgpass.

Why is the user wrong? Why am I unable to connect to the database?

Thanks in advance for the help. Apologies if there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: 1) `env` variables set?  2) Pointing at correct version of `'my_service'` file?

Comment: Did you add 'myapp' to the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings variable?

Comment: @Igor I have added myapp to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) Which`env` variables are you talking about? 2) I don't have a `'my_service'` file.. is this an important component I'm missing?

Comment: 1) [env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) variables. 2) Yes if you are referring to it here: `'service': 'my_service',`